# How to setup PC router to monitor LAN traffic?

Tags: networking, router, raspberrypi, traffic

I'm sure I can turn a pc or a raspberry pi into a router.

I'm just wondering if I can use this router to monitor traffic? I mean say I have four terminal devices owned by different person in my home, can I get statistics on the data going through to each device when I experience sluggishness browsing the internet? I want to get an idea who's consuming the data the most.

If it's possible, how can I do it? Is raspberry pi capable of doing this? Any instructions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite tool for this task is `ipfm` ("IP Flow Meter"). In contract to `wireshark` it does not require to log the actual content of the traffic, and in contrast to `ntop` it does not aggregate transferred data from when you start looking at the tool. It aggregates traffic data permanently and saves the result in log files.

**Installation:**

```
sudo apt install ipfm
```

**Configuration:** Edit `/etc/ipfm.conf` while looking at the documentation in `man ipfm.conf`.

**Usage:**

- Start it with `sudo ipfm`
- After config file changes, restart it with `sudo killall ipfm && sudo ipfm`.
- To see results, look at the log files it writes, as you configured in `/etc/ipfm.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your need wireshark would be goof for your need, you can install it from their website or through PPA if it isn't available in your repositories (which i think will be the case if you are using a raspberry pi) But you have to be careful as the pi might not be able to handle all this information.

the method to do this in Ubuntu is with the following commands, I don't think it'll be very different for the pi:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
sudo groupadd wireshark
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark YOUR_USER_NAME
sudo chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo chmod 750 /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /usr/bin/dumpcap
sudo getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

Also check out this: http://sectools.org/tag/traffic-monitors/  this is great for monitoring data but fairly advanced to operate, although you will find tutorials and forums for it as well.

BTW: If you are running this on a normal PC it should be fine, and also after rereading your question i saw that there isn't actually that much data so the Pi should be fine as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I've tried Wireshark on my Mac. It didn't provide me other device's traffic info but mine. I will have a look at it today and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use a raspberry pi, then you will in to install a Linux server edition, which don't have a graphical environment that will consume lots of resources for nothing.

You can install ntop :
http://www.ntop.org/get-started/download/

It just do everything.

You even have a version for Ras pi.